# Enable Vaadin Flow Production Mode in Spring Initializr Gradle Project

Tags: java, spring, gradle, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I run into confusion while trying to set a `com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter` Gradle project into production mode.

The project is part of a multi-module project and its (simplified) `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:${vaadinVersion}"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter")

    // ... futher more
}
```

I've found several projects and documentation focusing this topic, such as:

- [Vaadin Maven Plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin-maven-plugin)
- [Flow Maven Plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/flow-maven-plugin)
- [Gradle Vaadin Flow Plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.devsoap/gradle-vaadin-flow-plugin)
- [Setting Flow into Production Mode with Maven](https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/production/tutorial-production-mode-basic.html)

My current state is that I added `vaadin.productionMode=true` to the `application.yaml` file, which causes the following error on HTTP GET:

> Failed to find the bundle manifest file 'frontend://vaadin-flow-bundle-manifest.json' in the servlet context for 'ES6' browsers. If you are running a dev-mode servlet container in maven e.g. `jetty:run` change it to `jetty:run-exploded`. If you are not compiling frontend resources, include the 'vaadin-maven-plugin' in your build script. Otherwise, you can skip this error either by disabling production mode, or by setting the servlet parameter 'original.frontend.resources=true'.

So in general, I think that I'm on the right way.

- `Setting the servlet parameter 'original.frontend.resources=true'` removes the error, but it seems like a work-around to me, thus I want to avoid it.
- `Disabling production mode` is obviously not an option :-)

So my question is: How can I include the `vaadin-maven-plugin` in my Gradle build script. As I am using Flow only, should I rather use the `flow-maven-plugin`?

---

Update 1: I want to set a [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) Gradle project with Vaadin dependency into production mode. I do not want to create a new `gradle-vaadin-flow-plugin` project.

Answer (score 3):

The Gradle equivalent of `vaadin-maven-plugin` would be `com.devsoap.vaadin-flow` ([1](https://github.com/devsoap/gradle-vaadin-flow/wiki/Getting-started-%28no-IDE%29)), and you also need to configure `vaadin { productionMode = true }` in  `build.gradle` ([2](https://github.com/devsoap/gradle-vaadin-flow/wiki/Building-for-production))

It's also possible to configure the gradle property so that it depends on a build time parameter, as explained [here](https://devsoap.com/production-ready-gradle-vaadin-flow-applications/): configure `vaadin.productionMode = findProperty('productionMode') ?: false` in `build.gradle`, and add a placeholder in the `@VaadinServletConfiguration` that will be preprocessed when building the project.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried to create the project and it works. However, I do not intend to widely refactor the current project configuration and/or dependencies, which seems to be necessary for this plugin. Isn't there a way to simply enable the production mode in the above-mentioned, existing `build.gradle`?

Comment: "Production Mode" has two parts: compiling the ES5/ES6 bundles (that is done by `vaadin-maven-plugin` when using maven, and `com.devsoap.vaadin-flow` with gradle) and also configuring the application so that those bundles are actually served. The latter can be achived by setting the `-Dvaadin.productionMode` system property on runtime, or 
setting the `productionMode` web application property in true. Alternatively, a conditional dependency with `flow-server-production-mode` should do the trick too.

Comment: The second part is achieved by adding `vaadin.productionMode=true` to the `application.yaml` file. As I understood, I cannot use `vaadin-maven-plugin` since I use Gradle. I also cannot use `com.devsoap.vaadin-flow` since I want to keep the `build.gradle` structure provided by Spring Initializr. Is there no other simpler option to "flip the bit"? If not, I cannot compile ES5/ES6 bundles and I have to set `vaadin.original.frontend.resources=true`. Which disadvantages would that cause?

Comment: The first part is pretty complex, since it requires transpilation of all the web components used by the application (both your own web components, and those from webjars), and that involves bower and other JS tools; then you should replicate what the maven/gradle plugins do. See, for instance https://vaadin.com/docs/flow/production/tutorial-production-mode-advanced.html

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, I now understand the purpose and the related complexity. However, after all I do not really believe that a Spring Boot Starter project doesn't allow for production ready artifacts. I'd like to keep the question open for a while.

Comment: As far as I know the com.devsoap.vaadin-flow gradle plugin is the official recommendation of Vaadin Flow guys when building with gradle. I tested the plugin in my spring boot project and basically it worked with some limitations.